# xpathSApply skip if text equals postseason

Tags: r, xpath

I'm running into a road block here and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I need to skip over the link if the text equals postseason.  The text is in the second li in the xpaths below in my code.

I tried `li[not(.,"postseason")]` as I thought that is what I needed to exclude the postseason link but it doesn't work.

This link will show you an example of want I want to exclude under standard batting > game logs > postseason

http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/j/jeterde01.shtml

place this http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/j/jeterde01.shtml in `playerURLs` and you should season the postseason link returned.  How can I skip over the postseason link?  Thanks!

```
#GET YEARS PLAYED LINKS 


yplist = NULL 

playerURLs <- paste("http://www.baseball-reference.com",datafile17[,c("hrefs")],sep="") 

for(thisplayerURL in playerURLs){ 

doc <- htmlParse(thisplayerURL) 
yplinks <- data.frame( 
  names =  xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@id="all_standard_batting"]/div//ul/li[2]/ul/li/a',xmlValue), 
  hrefs = xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@id="all_standard_batting"]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li/a',xmlGetAttr,'href')) 

yplist = rbind(yplist, yplinks) 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [r](/questions/tagged/r) language specifically, but from xpath point of view, you can use `. != "..."` or `not(contains(.,"..."))` predicate pattern to exclude element having specific inner text value.

The following will exclude `<li>` having inner text *exactly equals* `"postseason"` :

```
li[. != "postseason"]
```

This one will exclude `<li>` having inner text *like* `"postseason"`

```
li[not(contains(.,"postseason"))]
```